# PHP Resolving URL format with Base URL Relative Path into Absolute

Tags: php

I get some html code from other website. Using Bellow Code

```php
$content =  file_get_contents('http://something.net/path/test.php');
```

From Here I get like this code

```
<div class="main"><a href="/testother.php?abhijit=1">Test One</a></div>
<div class="main"><a href="top.php?kumar=1">Test One</a></div>
<div class="main"><a href="/testother.php?abhijit=3">Test One</a></div>
<div class="main"><a href="ww.php?kumar=1">Test One</a></div>
```

I get all the href attribute by using Regex.

```
/testother.php?abhijit=1
top.php?kumar=1
/testother.php?abhijit=3
ww.php?kumar=1
//otherdomain.com/something.php
```

Now all this links has no domain and paths

But I want to get all this links like bellow(I hope all links are format link this)

```
http://something.net/testother.php?abhijit=1
http://something.net/path/top.php?kumar=1
http://something.net/test/other.php?abhijit=3
http://something.net/path/ww.php?kumar=1
```

How can I transform relative path into absolute URL using PHP.

By use my main `URL` and the href attributs links with PHP.

**(THANKS)**

Comment: is `http://something.net/` the current page domain ?

Comment: `top.php?kumar=1` this are going to `http://something.net/path/top.php?kumar=1` right.

Comment: Well, just concatenate both tokens...

Comment: `top.php?kumar=1` this are going to `http://something.net/path/top.php?kumar=1` and `/testother.php?abhijit=1` are go to `http://something.net//testother.php?abhijit=1` path are the headek

Comment: @ABHIJIT, `top.php?kumar=1` it is already goes to` OR it's must go to ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Transform Relative Path Into Absolute URL Using PHP**

```php
function rel2abs($rel, $base) {
    /* return if already absolute URL */
    if (parse_url($rel, PHP_URL_SCHEME) != '') return $rel;

    /* queries */
    if ($rel[0] == '?') return explode("?", $base)[0] . $rel;

    /* anchors */
    if ($rel[0] == '#') return explode("#", $base)[0] . $rel;

    /* parse base URL and convert to local variables: $scheme, $host, $path */
    extract(parse_url($base));

    /* Url begins with // */
    if ($rel[0] == '/' && $rel[1] == '/') {
        return "$scheme:$rel";
    }

    /* remove non-directory element from path */
    $path = preg_replace('#/[^/]*$#', '', $path);

    /* destroy path if relative url points to root */
    if ($rel[0] == '/') $path = '';

    /* dirty absolute URL */
    $abs = "$host$path/$rel";

    /* replace '//' or '/./' or '/foo/../' with '/' */
    $re = array('#(/\.?/)#', '#/(?!\.\.)[^/]+/\.\./#');
    for ($n = 1; $n > 0; $abs = preg_replace($re, '/', $abs, -1, $n)) {}

    /* absolute URL is ready! */
    return "$scheme://$abs";
}
```

**Testing ...**

```php
echo '<h4>Queries</h4>';
echo rel2abs("?query=1", "http://something.net/path/test.php");
echo '<br>';
echo rel2abs("?query=1", "http://something.net/path/test.php?old_query=1");

echo '<h4>Anchors</h4>';
echo rel2abs("#newAnchores", "http://something.net/path/test.php?a=1");
echo '<br>';
echo rel2abs("#newAnchores", "http://something.net/path/test.php?a=1#something");

echo '<h4>Path</h4>';
echo rel2abs("/testother.php", "http://something.net/folder1/folder2/folder3/test.php");
echo '<br>';
echo rel2abs("./../../testother.php", "http://something.net/folder1/folder2/folder3/test.php");
echo '<br>';
echo rel2abs("./../testother.php", "http://something.net/folder1/folder2/folder3/test.php");
echo '<br>';
echo rel2abs("./testother.php", "http://something.net/folder1/folder2/folder3/test.php");
echo '<br>';
echo rel2abs("testother.php", "http://something.net/folder1/folder2/folder3/test.php");

echo '<h4>Url begins with //</h4>';
echo rel2abs("//google.com/path/", "https://something.net/path/test.php");
echo '<br>';
echo rel2abs("//google.com/path/", "http://something.net/path/test.php");
```

**Test Output ...**

```
Queries

http://something.net/path/test.php?query=1
http://something.net/path/test.php?query=1

Anchors

http://something.net/path/test.php?a=1#newAnchores
http://something.net/path/test.php?a=1#newAnchores

Path

http://something.net/testother.php
http://something.net/folder1/testother.php
http://something.net/folder1/folder2/testother.php
http://something.net/folder1/folder2/folder3/testother.php
http://something.net/folder1/folder2/folder3/testother.php

Url begins with //

https://google.com/path/
http://google.com/path/
```